# Merging multiple JSON files into single JSON file in S3 from AWS Lambda python function

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am strucked in my work where my requirement is combining multiple json files into single json file and need to compress it in s3 folder

Somehow I did but the json contents are merging in dictionary and I know I have used Dictionary to load my json content from files because I tried with loading as List but it throws mw JSONDecodeError "Extra data:line 1 column 432(431)"

my file looks like below:
file1 (no .json extension will be there)

```
{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321"}
```

file 2

```
{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321":"hqeddeqf":"5765354"}
```

my code-

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name='<my bucket>'

def lambda_handler(event,context):
 key='<Bucket key>'
 jsonfilesname = ['<name of the json files which stored in list>']
 result=[]
 json_data={}
 for f in (range(len(jsonfilesname))):
  s3_client.download_file(bucket_name,key+jsonfilesname[f],'/tmp/'+key+jsonfilesname[f])
  infile = open('/tmp/'+jsonfilesname[f]).read()
  json_data[infile] = result
 with open('/tmp/merged_file','w') as outfile:
  json.dump(json_data,outfile)
```

my output for the outfile by the above code is

```
{
"{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321"}: []",
"{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321":"hqeddeqf":"5765354"} :[]"
}
```

my expectation is:

```
{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321"},{"abc":"bcd","12354":"31354321":"hqeddeqf":"5765354"}
```

Please someone help and advice what needs to be done to get as like my expected output

Comment: At this line of code: `json_data[infile] = result`, `infile` is the text that was read from the JSON file, and result is an empty array. That's why you get the results you see. You should probably use `json_data.push(infile)`. Also, your expected output is not valid JSON. Did you mean to wrap the two objects in an array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

`file 2` is not a valid JSON file, correctly it should be:

```
{
    "abc": "bcd",
    "12354": "31354321",
    "hqeddeqf": "5765354"
}
```

Also, the output is not a valid JSON file, what you would expect after merging 2 JSON files is an array of JSON objects:

```
[
    {
        "abc": "bcd",
        "12354": "31354321"
    },
    {
        "abc": "bcd",
        "12354": "31354321",
        "hqeddeqf": "5765354"
    }
]
```

Knowing this, we could write a Lamdda to merge JSONS files:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    bucket = '...'
    jsonfilesname = ['file1.json', 'file2.json']
    result=[]
    for key in jsonfilesname:
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        content = json.loads(data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8"))
        result.append(content)

    # Do something with the merged content
    print(json.dumps(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS, I would recommend using [S3DistCp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)
for json file merging as it provides a fault-tolerant, distributed way that can keep up with large files as well by leveraging MapReduce
. However, it does not seem to support `in-place` merging.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).